# Pycharm: Update virtualenv when requirements.txt changes

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm, I have a `virtualenv` that was autogenerated based on an existing `requirements.txt` file as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#env-requirements).

> PyCharm can create a virtual environment for your project based on the project requirements.

> Open any directory with your source files that contains the requirements.txt or setup.py file:

> If no virtual environment has been created for this project, PyCharm suggests creating it

Now I can configure this `virtualenv` as interpreter for my Pycharm projects.

*(BTW: I found that - unlike documented - the interpreter/virtualenv can be shared between projects, as you can locate it also outside of the project.)*

**Question**: Is there a way of updating the autogenerated `virtualenv`, when the corresponding `requirements.txt` changed?

So far, the only way I found was to manually modify the individual packages in the configuration of this `virtualenv` in the Pycharm GUI.

Comment: Generally, assuming updating means installing new requirements, you can do `venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt` and `pip` command will update the virtual environment with newly installed packages.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Sure, this is what effectively happens on the lower level. I was wondering if this is also supported in the GUI. Ideally, PyCharm would detect a newer requirements file. I was anyway wondering, why the `virtualenv` configuration does not contain the path to the requirements file it originated from (if any).

Comment: Isn't [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) what you are looking for?

BTW. It uses other file format (not `requirements.txt`), but from what I understood, it provides the feature you desire.

Comment: As far as I know `pipenv` keeps the bond with `Pipfile.lock` (replacement to `requirements.txt`) so whenever you adjust your depencies, your virtualenv is also updated (they are kept integrated).

This is a bit different way of managing dependencies, but I thought this is what you are trying to achieve. Is it?

Comment: @Maciek I have seen PyCharm offering to create a virtual environment based on `pipenv` but did not use it so far. What you say sounds interesting and would indeed meet my requierements - given that Pycharm can leverage this bonding for automatic updates. I guess I need to read up on this topic before I can give a definitive answer.